# Complete the square on cross terms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to complete the square on $xy - xz + yz = 1$.

I have tried plugging in $u = x + y$. But I still end up with unsolvable cross terms.

Comment: I don't see a square anywhere...

Comment: Perhaps you should "complete the square" for each term separately, then combine the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: the surface $xy-zx+yz=1$ is a rotated version of the surface of revolution $x^2 + y^2 = 1 + 2 z^2,$ which is a hyperboloid of one sheet.

The first matrix identity below, $Q^T DQ=H,$ says that
$$ \frac{1}{4}(x+y)^2 - \frac{1}{4}(-x+y-2z)^2 + z^2 = xy - zx + yz \; . $$
This displays the three variables
$$ u=x+y, \; \; v = -x + y - 2 z, \; \; w = z \; .   $$
Sylvester's Law of Inertia says that there are two positive and one negative eigenvalue of the Hessian matrix of $xy-zx + yz.$ Setting it equal to $1$ gives a hyperboloid of one sheet.

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Also, we can use the fact that the eigenvalues of the original matrix are integers to find an orthogonal matrix that gives us

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt 6 } &  \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt 3 } \\ 
  \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt 6 } & - \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt 3 } \\ 
0 &   \frac{ 2 }{ \sqrt 6 } &  \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt 3 } \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{\sqrt 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt2 }  & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{\sqrt 6 }  & \frac{ 1 }{\sqrt 6 } &   \frac{ 2 }{\sqrt 6 } \\ 
\frac{ 1 }{\sqrt 3 } & -\frac{ 1 }{\sqrt 3 } & \frac{ 1 }{\sqrt 3 } \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
which shows that the hyperboloid is a surface of revolution

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$

$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 2):

All you can do is $y(x+z)=1$ then divide by one or the other if it suits you.  There is no square to complete.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to read the whole question.

Comment: Better than I can write. Congratulations!